# How to prove the following functions h.g(n) = O(f(n))

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

Given that,

> Let f(n) = O(g(n)), let g(n) = O(h(n)), what could be the functions of f(n), g(n) and h(n) to make the following true h.g(n) = O(f(n)).

I have tried like every possible solution. for example let f(n) = g(n) = h(n) = n.

so f(n) is big O of g(n) is true, and g(n) is a big O of h(n), but h.g = O(f(n)) that's of course false. because i'm going to get n^2, if it was    Ω
 notation instead of Big O, that would be fairly easy to prove.

i have tried different functions *polynomial, logs, exponential functions* none of them worked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming problem. It is a math problem.

Comment: @RaymondChen thank you for your concerns, that's why i have the asymptotic-complexity and algorithms tags and this question is related to algorithms, and a lot of other users have posted similar questions, and their questions are not closed.

Comment: f(n)=g(n)=h(n)=1 appears to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume `h(x)` is `OMEGA(x)`, that would mean for there must exist some constant positive values `x', a,b,c,d` such that for any `x>x'`, the following holds: 
`f(x) <= a*g(x), g(x) <= b*h(x)` and `d*f(x) >= h(g(x)) >= c*g(x) >= c*a*f(x)`, which means that in fact `g` and `f` are asymptotically equivalent and both are `o(x)`, but `h(x)` is actually `Theta(x)`(otherwise contradiction) - this leads to one set of solutions

Now assume `h(x)` is `o(x)`, that would mean that all `f,g,h` are in fact `o(x)`. That would mean we can pick any `h(x)` from `[O(1):o(x)]`, and pick any `g(x)`, such that `g(x)` is `[O(1):o(h)]` and then pick any `f` from range of `[OMEGA[h(g(x)), o(g(x))]` which has to exist due to `h` being `o(x)`. These leads to second set of solutions (infinite number, based on choice of `h(x)`)

**NOTE:Assumption is that all functions are increasing and at least o(1)**

---

> IGNORE THE FOLLOWING - incorrectly understood the question

**This does not answer the question, but may be of help**

Obviously all three function `f,g,h` are `O(1)`. Easy to see why:
There must exist some constant positive values `x', a,b,c` such that for any `x>x'`, the following holds: 
`f(x) <= a*g(x), g(x) <= b*h(x), h(x)*g(x) <= c*f(x)`, so

> c*f(x) >= h(x)*g(x) >= a*b*f(x)*f(x), or f(x) =< c/(b*a)

so we can conclude that `f(x)` is in fact `O(1)`
Furthermore,

> C >= c*f(x) >= h(x)*g(x) >= g(x)*g(x)*b

So `g(x)` is `O(1)` too.

Lastly

> c*f(x) >= h(x)*g(x) >= h(x)*f(x)*a, or h(x) <= c/a

All three function are `O(1)`. An example would be `f(x)=1/(x^3), g(x)=1/x^2,h(x)=1/x`

Comment: h.g(n) = h(g(n)), not h(n) * g(n).

Comment: Thank you :), that's the only case that i didn't think about